# integral of $\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

In Quora question about the country with the hardest math curriculum, someone posted a picture of integrals that students compute in Vietnamese high schools.

The first integral there transforms to the integral of 
$\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin(x)$. Am I correct to believe that the antiderivative of this function cannot be expressed in elementary functions,
i.e. you cannot compute the indefinite integral?

Comment: Could you link the Quora answer with this question?

Comment: Is this a definite integral, or indefinite? If it's indefinite, I feel that there is no solution in elementary functions. Perhaps$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}dx\,\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin x$$

Comment: Is it this answer: https://www.quora.com/Which-country-has-the-hardest-Mathematics-in-their-education-curriculum/answer/H-M-Đức?

Comment: @Crescendo yes, the first integral in the list, $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x}dx$

Comment: OK, I see that the definite integral of $\int_{-a}^{a}\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin(x)dx$ is zero. I guess I lost a sense of those questions a bit... The question about antiderivative is still valid though

Comment: we find for $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x}dx=\frac{\pi -4}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$